# Setting animation repeatbehaviour to forever through c# silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I'm just trying to make my basic animation run indefinitely by setting the repeatbehavior property of my animation to forever. I know I can do this and have managed to do this through the xaml but I am just wondering how to do this through the c# code and can't really find an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't believe no one has answered this one yet. :)

All you need to do is,

```
  var storyboard = new Storyboard() { RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
```

Hope this helps!